# Ensuring ActualWidth does not equal 0 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, actualwidth

So I've read that `ActualWidth` may equal 0 until it is fully loaded. I added its event handler, like so, to make sure it's fully loaded:

```
text.AddHandler(TextBlock.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(textBlock_Loaded));
```

In the `textBlock_Loaded` event, I have:

```
TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
textBlockWidth = tb.ActualWidth;
```

I need to use the variable `textBlockWidth` in my main method, but everytime I write the value of textBlockWidth to output in my Main method, I get 0.

**So this question is**, how do I ensure that `ActualWidth` is NOT 0 before performing my actions? Since WPF is event-driven, is there a way I can trigger some method when it's done, instead of before? Otherwise, it'll return 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to get the `ActualWidth`. Since, it will not be updated at the time of loaded. So, you should use Dispatcher of the `TextBlock` or it's Parent to get the `ActualWidth` or `ActualHeight`.

```
this.textBlock.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                textBlock = this.textBlock.ActualWidth;
            }));
```

Comment: I've already tried an approach like this- but my problem is that it never is loaded when I need it. After I called this in my main and set the ActualWidth into a variable, I proceeded to use this variable (in my main method). It will still return zero, as it still wasn't loaded yet.

Comment: It should be working. Instead of control's dispatcher could you please try the parent windows dispatcher. That would help it looks.

Like, this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452246/how-to-invoke-wpf-dispatcher-in-nunit

Comment: Hi DMan, I tried like this, inside the window Loaded event everything is fine. `  this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(this.textBlock.ActualWidth);
                        Console.WriteLine("Her");
                    }));
                }; `

Answer (score 5):

Why store the actual width? Why not store a reference to the control and get the actual width when you really need it?

Having said that I don't see why your code is failing as using the loaded event should be good enough. According to the [Object Lifetime Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx) MSDN page:

> The Loaded event is raised before the final rendering, but after the layout system has calculated all necessary values for rendering.

So all the controls should have their final position and size values set. Also:

> the Loaded event is raised as a coordinated effort throughout the entire element tree (specifically, the logical tree). When all elements in the tree are in a state where they are considered loaded, the Loaded event is first raised on the root element. The Loaded event is then raised successively on each child element.

Comment: I think it fails because the TextBlock's loaded event triggers _after_ my code in Main() that uses it.

Comment: Maybe "calculated all necessary values for rendering" means only that DesiredSize was calculated?

Comment: @HCL - could be. I couldn't find any more relevant information on that page or links that would explain that fully.

Comment: Can you tell me how I should store a reference to the control?

Comment: @Dave: Introducing misspellings in 3 year old answers is not helpful.

Comment: @Ben this was part of a retagging effort to have these questions more searchable.